# nose python27 and sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nosetests

I've installed python27 using MacPorts and have added the /opt/local/bin path to the PATH variable. When I execute `which python` I get the one installed at `/opt/local/bin` which is fine. However , I installed nose using easy_install and nosetests now is installed in /usr/local/bin. There is a nosetests-2.7 in /opt/local/bin as well. I've tried running that one:

```
/opt/local/bin/nosetests-2.7  --exe sklearn
```

However, after a bunch of warnings and successful tests I end up getting the following:

```
ERROR: sklearn.cluster.bicluster.tests.test_utils.test_get_submatrix
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/nose/case.py", line 197, in runTest
    self.test(*self.arg)
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cluster/bicluster/tests/test_utils.py", line 43, in test_get_submatrix
    assert_true(np.all(X != -1))
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 422, in assertTrue
    if not expr:
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py", line 183, in __bool__
    raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1715 tests in 112.607s

FAILED (SKIP=16, errors=1)
```

Not sure why `File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg/nose/case.py"` is  being executed when I clearly ran the nosetests from /opt/local/bin directory.

Any help on this would be really appreciated!

UPDATE:

Results of: `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'`

"['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Theano-0.6.0-py2.7.egg', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy-0.13.2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']"

Comment: What does `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` say?

Comment: added the result of the command in the question!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a numerical stability issue in this specific test. I would not wary much about it unless your are specifically interested in using the bi-clustering model on that platform.

You can also try to build the current master of scikit-learn from git. This test might have been stabilized since the last release (although I am not 100% sure).